# fortran90 reading real numbers from file odd results

Tags: floating-point, fortran, precision, fortran90

```
real*8, dimension (40) :: M(40)

...    

open(unit=99,file="input.inp")
do i=1,40
    read(99,*) M(i)
enddo

write(*,*) M(1)
...
```

In the file "input.inp", I have float numbers, like:

```
0.85
0.90
...
```

But when I read and write them on terminal, it gives me the first element: 0.849999...

How can I fix it to give me exact 0.85?

Edit: I compile it on gfortran. lol

Comment: The exact value of 0.85 is 0.84999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375

Comment: set the precision to 2 or more decimal digits

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Had somebody added the fortran tag my close vote would have closed it immediately.